# How can I check if a table or view exists in Oracle DB using javascript?

Tags: javascript, oracle, exists

I need to check if a table name from html input exists in an oracle database, how can I do that?

Comment: What is you way of communication toward the DB?  You probably have some thing between the browser and the DB.

Comment: Unless javascript is your backend code (a la node.js), you need some sort of backend interface for javascript to talk to (through AJAX for example).

Comment: Technically  you have use Applets with JDBC to directly connect to the DB.  But you probably need to go over the body of several system operators and security Cerberus  to have the needed port open.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the lack of information in the question. I have a html-php-javascript page where I have a field which the user must complete with the proper DB table like "Select from "user inserted table" where..." and I don't want to let the user send wrong information to the DB so I want to make a check first. Thanks and sorry again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot access a db from client side (javascript browser). You need to expose, server side, a service which accepts in the GET call a parameter string, the table name, and call this server with an ajax call client side, using javascript and sending the required table name string into the GET body of the ajax call.

The server will receive the table name, check it against its db wit a proper query, then return the result to the client that will parse the server result as GET return value and perform the desired action

EDIT: answering to the comment, you need to query your db searching for your table, let's say named your-table-name, in your db user_tables executing the following query via php:

```
SELECT table_name FROM user_tables where table_name = 'your-table-name'
```

and then check if the query returns one record (the table exists) or none (the table doesn't exist).

Comment: Oh, as I've said before, sorry for the lack of information regarding my problem, it's my first question on stack overflow. The thing is I use php as the server side and to connect the DB, maybe from php I could do it? What do you think? thanks!

Comment: Ok, so, how can I do that? Can you help me with any suggestions? I mean, I connect to the DB from php, and when I insert the table name in html, I'm already in client side..so I can't go back to php..Thanks!